# How to make a Login with a txt file in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to develop a login using a txt file My problem is at `if (Authenticator.equals(un+" "+pw))` it is not coming through true and is moving to my else statement. Why is my statement not  true? I know its checking only the first line..... suggestions anyone? [image: what I have in the note pad and the printed results]

```
private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
                String un = UserName.getText().trim();
                String pw = Password.getText().trim();
            try {
                Scanner Scan = new Scanner(new File("Login.txt"));            
                System.out.println(Scan.nextLine().trim());
                String Authenticator = Scan.nextLine().trim();
                    if (Authenticator.equals(un+" "+pw)){
                    System.out.println("sweetness");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("bummer");
                    }
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            System.out.println(un+" "+pw);                 
        }
```

Comment: Try to remove `System.out.println(Scan.nextLine().trim());`, and see, if it still happens. Seems to me, since you calling `nextLine()` inside `System.out`, hence the cursor moves to the next line, though you wanted to check the first username and password. What is the value of `JPasswordField`, that you trying to compare. Moreover, consider using `char` array instead of `String`s for password, related work. Please do try to follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), before posting or learning how to code. +1 though for ingredients

Comment: Local variable names should start with lower case letters - rename `Authenticator` to `authenticator`.

Comment: @user1803551, Naming conversions not cause any issues with Compiler. Its only up to us to follow the naming conversations for the reliability of code.

Comment: @AnilReddy And where did i mention anything about a compiler?

Comment: hey! I did what you suggested! It worked! your awesome! Thank you Thank you! thank you! I have been trying to get that result for 3 days now lol. (well technically 2 with the change in methods)  This is an important lesson here. I had no idea that the System.out.println(Scan.nextLine().trim()); would impact my results

Comment: thank you, I will fix that! I knew about the conventions, but I am not super detailed on those.

Comment: It's the call `Scan.nextLine()` (inside `println`) that causes the problem. It advances the scanner to the next line so it won't be read later on.

Comment: that makes sense. I will want it to read another line and check it. but I haven't attempted to  figure that part out yet. Thank you everyone! my 3 day + problem has now been solved.